# .serialize() returns empty dict. What do i do wrong?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, serialization

What's wrong with this? .serialize() returns nothing. I've tried several ways to do this, but all end up with empty dictionary. form, input, #idofform, #idofinput, nothing happens...

```
 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("/resultjs/", $("form").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('.content').html(data);
            });
});
```

...and html. just a normal simple form. To be completely clear: I would like collect post data from the form, post them to /resultjs/ (django), retrieve the result and write it to .content div

<div id="search">   

<form action="/resultjsall/" method="post"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='somedjangocsrftoken' /></div>

<input type="text" name="what" id="what" value="" size="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
</div>

Comment: What are the contents of your form? Only some form elements are supported.

Comment: Also if you have more than 1 form, this will serialize the data from all your forms and aggregate it into a single string. Not usually what you want, since you only submit one form.

Comment: If you run this when the document is ready, your form will probably be empty, so most probably you end up with the variables being sent but with no values (i.e. `.serialize()` will return something like `"name1=&name2="`)

Comment: remember serialization is based off of the _name_ not _id_ of the input elements in your form, just like normal... make sure the inputs in the form have `name` attributes

Comment: @Dan I think you should have posted your comment as an answer

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure if I getting it right, but when I remove the .ready() it's just the same...

Comment: @nanook: don't remove the ready(). It's just that you need another event handler, which is the submitting of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your `$.post` only upon submitting the function (hence the event handler `<form_selector>.submit( ... )`, see [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Notice that I kept the `$(document).ready` part. The purpose of that is to wait for all other scripts and the DOM to load before doing stuff such as binding events to elements in the DOM (such as that form), because if the elements you're binding to aren't loaded at the time the binding executes, nothing will happen instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#myForm").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), 
          function(data) {
            if (data == "") { alert("No data returned!"); return; }
            // otherwise set the content div to the data we received
            $('div.content').html(data);
          }
        );
        // disable normal submitting of the form since we use ajax now
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your form submission to the clicking of the submit button. Do something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form input[type='submit']").click(function() {
        $.post($("form").attr("action"), $("form").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('.content').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: it's `form:input`, the selector `.input` looks for elements of class `input` :) and a good idea would be to also qualify the form with an id/name/anything (like `"form#formId"` and `"form#formId:input[type='submit']"`, in case you add another form sometime, because it will break then.

Comment: You're right, the selector was wrong. Actually I'd rather see "form input", because I'm selecting the input, not the form itself. Yes I realise that there is no ID specified, but the code given didn't include it, and rather than focus on other things I wanted to focus on the main problem of the form not being submitted. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: YES. I see now. Thanks a lot to all.